# Mapping Reduction from HALT?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, reductions, halting-problem, decidability

I've been given a task to determine whether L={〈M〉|M is a TM that loops on the input c (a constant)} is decidable. I can prove co-L is recognizable so I figured a reduction from HALT to co-L would finish my proof that L isn't even recognizable. Now I'm stuck. I just can't seem to master creating mapping reductions.

I know I need to develop f() where: if (〈M〉,w) is in HALT, then f(〈M〉,w) = 〈M'〉 is in co-L
and if (〈M〉,w) is **not** in HALT, then 〈M'〉 is **not** in co-L but I've wasted a day and a half on this on reduction.

I'd really appreciate some guidance on a general strategy for developing the function, f(). I keep getting caught up in w versus c and the input (which I called x) to M'.

Thank you for any direction.

Comment: Hi , what does $M'$ in $\langle M' \rangle$ denote?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I meant ⟨M′⟩ to denote the output of f() which would be a TM description.

Comment: So you meant "... $f(\langle M, w \rangle) = \langle M' \rangle$ is in co-L ..." instead of "... $f(\langle M' \rangle)$ is in co-L..."?
You can use the "edit" button right below your question to fix that section if that's the case.

Comment: Thanks. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Define the reduction $f$ such that $f(\langle M, w \rangle) = \langle M' \rangle$, where $M'$ is a TM that on word $x$

1. simulates $M$ on $w$ if $x = c$
2. halts

It's easy to see that

$$M \text{ halts on } w \iff M' \text{ halts on } c$$

therefore

$$\langle M, w\rangle \in \texttt{HALT} \iff f(\langle M, w \rangle) = \langle M'\rangle \in \overline{L}.$$

So $\texttt{HALT} \preceq_{M} \overline{L}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for that answer. I tried that days ago. Why is this so hard to get? The definitions are straight-forward. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem 

Don't worry if you're having a hard time finding reductions, it's mostly a matter of experience.

Comment: Looking at this again today, shouldn't step 2 be loop? Otherwise, I'm not sure how you get M' halts on c ==> M halts on w (it seems that M' can halt on two different sets of conditions)?

Comment: And, if I may, where doe the input x to M' come from? I'm so confused. Or is M' assumed to run over the domain of co-L?

Comment: If step 2. was loop, then $L(M') = \emptyset$ since $M'$ would loop on any input.
When you run $M'$ on $c$, then $M'$ simulates $M(w)$.
So if $M(w)$ loops, then $M'(c)$ must loop as well.
If $M(w)$ terminates, then $M'(c)$ must terminate as well due to step 2.

Comment: Any input alphabet using which you can represent $c$ would work for $M'$.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking something like: 1. if x=c, simulate M on w; 2. if M accepts, accept; 3. loop. Is that the same?

Comment: That's not exactly the same.
$M$ could also halt rejecting, then $M$ would halt on $w$ but $M'$ would loop on $c$.

Comment: Thanks again. Change 2. to if M halts, accept. Oddly, I can't find a way to Reply and the system doesn't want more comments.